# Java, special sort an ArrayList with longer entries at the end

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList<String>` in Java. Now I want to sort it with some requirements.

I have these items in the ArrayList for example:

```
xyz
bcd
abc_locked
cde
efg_locked
fgh
```

And I want to push back the ones with `_locked` at the end and keep the order, to make this:

```
xyz
bcd
cde
fgh
abc_locked
efg_locked
```

What is the best way to do this?  Would I have to iterate through the List remove the String and just add it again? or is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hint: `Collections.sort(yourList, customComparator);`

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaCollections/#collectionssort

Comment: well i've got the aproach of iterating, but there musst be a cleaner way, a customComarator i.e. but i wouldnt know what that musst look like to make it do what i want ;)

Comment: Does the _locked item have to be sorted in specific order when they are push back at the end of the list like alphabetically or just by order of appearance is enough?

Comment: the order they are in

Comment: @M4tchB0X3r: If you show what you tried, I'm sure somebody will be willing to help you. But doing your job without any effort on your side will probably not happen...

Comment: `xyz` must be first in the sorted list?

Comment: @WilQu that was just an example, the list can come in lots of different orders, but i must retain it, just push the one with `_locked` back. @jlordo i have only got the approach of itarating and it works, but i would like to know how to do it with a customComparator, should have said sry

Comment: To be fair, it doesn't sound like the OP is asking anyone to do the work. It sounds like the OP understands how it can be done by removing/adding the necessary elements but wants to know if there's a better way. Now that the OP has been giving the [Collections.sort](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List<T>, java.util.Comparator<? super T>) idea, the OP can now try that

Comment: the OP is doing just that ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using this comparator:

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {

     @Override
     public int compare(String arg1, String arg2) {

         if (arg1.matches("^.*_locked$") && arg2.matches("^.*_locked$")) {
             // Both string have _locked at the end. Retain the order.
             return 0;
         } else if (arg1.matches("^.*_locked$")) {
             // First string have _locked. Swap.
             return 1;
         } else if (arg2.matches("^.*_locked$")) {
             // Second string have _locked. No need to swap
             return -1;
         } 

         // None of the string have _locked. Retain the order
         return 0;

     }
};

Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

Comment: awsome thx. just what i was looking for. First one i tried so im accepting. thx @all

Answer (score 1):

Use a comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator(){
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if ((o1.endsWith("_locked")&&(!o2.endsWith("_locked"))){
            return 1;
        }
        else if (!(o1.endsWith("_locked")&&(o2.endsWith("_locked"))){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            //Fallback sorting based on start of string left as exercise to reader
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an anonymous parametrized Comparator, as such:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("xyz");
myList.add("bcd");
myList.add("abc_locked");
myList.add("cde");
myList.add("efg_locked");
myList.add("fgh");
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
        if (!arg0.contains("_locked") && !arg1.contains("_locked")) {
            return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
        }
        else if (arg0.contains("_locked") && arg1.contains("_locked")) {
            return arg0.compareTo(arg1);
        }
        else if (arg0.contains("_locked")) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    };
});
System.out.println(myList);
```

Output:

```
[bcd, cde, fgh, xyz, abc_locked, efg_locked]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {

 @Override
 public int compare(String arg1, String arg2) {

     if (arg1.endsWith("_locked") && arg2.endsWith("_locked")) {
         return 0;
     } else if (arg1.endsWith("_locked")) {
         return 1;
     } else if (arg2.endsWith("_locked")) {
         return -1;
     } 
     return 0;
 }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

                // ascending order
                 return id1.compareTo(id2);

                // descending order
                //return id2.compareTo(id1);
            }
        });
```

For a collection of objects

```
/*
  Here myItems is an arraylist MyItem added randomly 
  MyItem got a property int id 
  This method provide me myItems in ascending order of id's
*/
Collections.sort(myItems, new Comparator<MyItem>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(MyItem lhs, MyItem rhs) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int lhsId = lhs.getId();
                int rhsId = rhs.getId();

                return lhsId>rhsId ? 1 : -1;
            }
        });
```

And of course you can refer [this](http://javatechig.com/java/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-in-java/)

Comment: Because OP is dealing with `String` and not `MyItem`. This answer basically has nothing to do with the question.